# How to convert an object to json using freezed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, json-serializable, flutter-freezed

I have written a [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) data class.

```
@freezed
class GithubRepoDTO with _$GithubRepoDTO {
  const GithubRepoDTO._();
  const factory GithubRepoDTO({
    required UserDTO owner,
    required String name,
    @JsonKey(fromJson: _fromJson) required String description,
    @JsonKey(name: 'stargazers_count') required int stargazersCount,
  }) = _GithubRepoDTO;

  factory GithubRepoDTO.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$GithubRepoDTOFromJson(json);

}
```

So I can write fromJson with freezed. But when I tried to have a toJson. I can't write it. So I used [jsonSerializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable), so now I can have a  toJson, this is the updated code.

```
@freezed
@JsonSerializable()
class GithubRepoDTO with _$GithubRepoDTO {
  const GithubRepoDTO._();
  const factory GithubRepoDTO({
    required UserDTO owner,
    required String name,
    @JsonKey(fromJson: _fromJson) required String description,
    @JsonKey(name: 'stargazers_count') required int stargazersCount,
  }) = _GithubRepoDTO;

  factory GithubRepoDTO.toGithubRepoDTO(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$GithubRepoDTOFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$GithubRepoDTOToJson(this);


}
```

Now I can have toJson, but in this way, the problem is now I need to name fromJson any other name , I cant use fromJson now, when i used it shows duplicated reference found on auto generated code. So here i renamed fromJson to toGithubRepoDTO.

1. Why can't I name fromJson same but for toJson i can name it same?
2. Is this approach correct?
3. Can i do this without json_serializable?

Answer (score 0):

According to freezed documentation you need to put `@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)` inside the class since you are using nested freezed objects (e.g. UserDTO). Also, you need to implement your custom json converter for the _fromJson method.

```
class YourJsonConverter extends JsonConverter<String?, String?> {
  const YourJsonConverter();
  // TODO implement from/toJson
}

@freezed
class GithubRepoDTO with _$GithubRepoDTO {
  const GithubRepoDTO._();
  @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
  const factory GithubRepoDTO({
    required UserDTO owner,
    required String name,
    @YourJsonConverter() required String description,
    @JsonKey(name: 'stargazers_count') required int stargazersCount,
  }) = _GithubRepoDTO;

  factory GithubRepoDTO.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$GithubRepoDTOFromJson(json);
}
```

Putting the `@JsonSerializable()` annotation inside the class will give you invalid annotation target warning. However, this is a known issue about the package and you can disable it as its mentioned [here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/488#issuecomment-894358980)

Now you can name it as fromJson since there are no duplicate fromJson methods in the generated code.

Comment: but still i cant use the same name as fromJson

Comment: @Akhil, I've updated the answer. Does this resolve your problem?

Comment: No, still its same, could you say why we need to change the fromJson when we are using toJson